# UFT is not able to recognize objects

Tags: qtp

An window based application which is developed in dot net and many CRM applications which is web based are integrated with window based application.

Problem here is using object spy or recording I'm able capture objects for both window and web based application. But when I'm running the test UFT is not able to navigate from window based application to web based application.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure all the add-ins required are loaded while executing the script. Also, add the title and class property to the browser object in OR. Dont leave the properties blank.